# Saving multiple visio diagrams to HTML

Tags: automation, visio

I am maintaining a set of process diagrams in visio 2007.  For viewing I save the files as HTML and publish them on a web server.

It works great but its a real pain to maintain (a paintain ;-).

I am looking for a way to do this as some kind of batch job, currently the process is:

- open each file
- file>save as web page
- in the save as web page dialogue:

  - select location
  - publish > open new dialogue
  - change title (i dont mind if i have to miss that step)
  - select web page to insert it into (my template)
- done

The tools I have availiable are:

- **Visual studio 2010 express** (i prefer c# but whatever)
- **Visio 2007**(i have another laptop with visio 2010 which i can use too but the source files will be 2007 - that's not changing for the moment)
- **Ruby** - may be easier if it doesn't require office integration.

(BTW I know about process repository in OSS 2010 and i have tested it with visio 2010 web diagrams - that works and would probably be a better option for anyone who has the choice, though its not perfect)

(batch file or command line would also be cool but i have not found a way of saving as web page from command line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visio's COM interop API to do what you want (I think).  I'd start by just recording a macro while manually doing the export, and then look at the VBA code that generates.  You could then adapt that in C#, or VBScript/VB6 if you want something you can call with a command shell.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon highlights, there's a whole API for using the SaveAsWeb functionality from code.  I wrote a post about it a little while ago, which you can see here:

http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2010/03/automating-visios-save-as-web-output.html

The post is VBA based but the .net version is very similar and there's also examples in the Visio 2010 SDK:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=12365